# Anonymous delegates in vb.net (pre vb9)?

Tags: vb.net, lambda

Is it possible to create anonymous delegates in vb.net version 8 or earlier?  If so, could someone provide an example of the syntax?  Thanks.

Comment: I initially forgot to limit my question to pre-lamba vb - sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB 9.0 you can create single line lambda expressions

```
Dim del = Function (x) x + 42
```

In VB 10.0 (not yet released).  You will be able to create both multiline function and sub routines (as well as single line subs).  For example

```
Dim del = Function (x)
            Return x + 42
          End Function
```

**EDIT** OP clarified it was for pre- VB 9.0

No, there is no way prior to VB 9.0 to create lambda expressions / anonymous delegates in VB.

Comment: Although it didn't answer the question, thanks for the info about VB10 anonymous delegates!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only in Visual Studio 2008/.Net 3.0 and later.

Use the Function keyword.